# Standard Error of the Regression for NLS Model

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I am currently working on a non-linear analysis of various datasets using nls model. On the other hand, I want to calculate the standard error of the regression of the nls model.

The formula of the standard error of regression:

```
n <- nrow(na.omit((data))

SE = (sqrt(sum(pv-av)^2)/(n-2))
```

where `pv` is the predicted value and `av` is the actual value.

I have a problem on calculating the standard error. Should I calculate the predicted value and actual value first? Are the values based on the dataset? Any help is highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: You can get predicted values using `predict(your_model, your_data)`, where `your_model` is the NLS model and `your_data` the data frame that went into it. Residuals can be found from `resid(your_model)`. But there's no need to calculate SE from scratch, unless you want to. The standard error of residuals can be obtained from `summary(your_model)$sigma`. Or you can look at the `broom` package for other methods to summarise models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R provides this via `sigma`:

```
fm <- nls(demand ~ a + b * Time, BOD, start = list(a = 1, b = 1))
sigma(fm)
## [1] 3.085016
```

This would also work where `deviance` gives residual sum of squares.

```
sqrt(deviance(fm) / (nobs(fm) - length(coef(fm))))
## [1] 3.085016
```